# Alert.prompt() alternative method in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, input

I am using React Native v 0.63.
I am trying to prompt an input box, which will console log in the output. However, Alert.prompt is deprecated now, instead, we can use Alert.alert().

I am trying to accomplish this.
[image]

```
Alert.prompt(
  'Enter password',
  'Enter your password to claim your $1.5B in lottery winnings',
  [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
      style: 'cancel'
    },
    {
      text: 'OK',
      onPress: (password) =>
        console.log('OK Pressed, password: ' + password)
    }
  ],
  'secure-text'
);
```

Now, this code snippet is not working. Instead, I am trying to using Alert.alert() with code, however, it's not working.
Is there an alternative method, which can open a pop-up input box and console the log?

Comment: You get to get the data that is inside of the input text ?

Comment: if a pass a value in the input components, it will show in the console

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the below npm package to prompt a user with the input and action buttons.

https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-dialog